# Multiprocessing in Python - how to use it in these loops?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The code below handles a huge amount of data and I want to ask how can I use the multiprocessing module in Python for parallel processing in order to speed things up.
Any help is appreciated

```
pats = []
for chunk in code_counter(patients, codes):
    pats.append(chunk)

def code_counter(patients, codes):
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(patients, key=operator.itemgetter('ID')):
        group_codes = [item['CODE'] for item in group]
        yield [group_codes.count(code) for code in codes]
```

Comment: Does the order of items in `pats` matter?

Comment: yes! do you know how to do it?

Comment: what is `patients` and where do you get it? for this to work, it must [alerady be sorted](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools#itertools.groupby) on `ID`.  Is it? Otherwise it would be better to just use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections#collections.Counter). Piping all data to subprocesses just to get a count back will probably introduce more overhead then speedgain.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem resides in the use of yield. I think you can't yield the data from different processes. I understood, that you use the yield cuz you can't load the data "inline"  that would cause the ram to overload.

maybe you can take a look at the multiprocessing Queue
http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

i didn't really get what you are trying to do with your code, so i can't deliver a precise excample.